# Decommissioning an iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Hi we have an iOS app in itunes which have more than 20,000 downloads.

since we have re-branded our company we have developed a new app which includes extra features than the existing app. New app is with new name and Bundle id.

So now rather than taking out the existing old app, we want to redirect all the existing users to our new app. How can we do that ?

what we did was , we updated the existing app version with the popup, which says this app no longer available please download our latest app. but this got rejected by apple.

Any best practices to decommission an ios app

Thanks

Comment: Why not put out the new app as an update to the old app? No need to decommission the old app.

Comment: well the new app is the update to the existing app we alredy had. but we have another app which we dont update but with less contents. so we want to redirect that users to our new updated one.

Comment: But I'm saying that there isn't a reason to have a new, separate app. Just update your old existing outdated app with the fancy new rebranded app. Why put out a new app? This means all existing users will get the fancy new update just by doing a normal app update. No need to redirect users to a different app.

Comment: Ok To make you clear we alredy had 2 iOS app. both have diffrent contents. The one we wanted to remove was sponsored app. their sponsored ship is now finished and we not gonna add any new contents to the app. But the other app we had is our app, which have wide range of contents including the contents in sponsored. Sponsored app is only for one sport content, so we have named the app to match the sport. so we cant rename the new app with that name or bundel id. so what we want is to migrate the users who are using sponsored app to our own app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple will not allow you to completely drop all of the features in an app - they want users to still be able to use the app. Imagine if all of a sudden Facebook make it so no one could use their app, and forced everyone to download a new app. It probably wouldn't turn out too good for them.

What you should do is just make an update to the old app. All of the users will be able to update easily, with no hassle, and you won't lose and users.

Another way to do this is by calling your new app MyAppName 2, although this will really only look good if you're developing a game.

If you would really like to get rid of your old app, I would recommend removing it from the app store and contacting Apple (You'll have to give them a good reason. Wanting people to pay for a new app doesn't count as one)

Comment: Yea , as per our management they dont wanna remove the app from itunes. still they wanna see the app in itunes. so what am planning is to check for the geolocation . if its US then show the original content. so Apple will see  normal app, but for other countries present a view controller to cover the entire window with some text and button to download our new app. do you think this will suits

Comment: @user2555373 It will probably work, but it is wrong to do for so many reasons. For one, you're directly bypassing the review, which may get your account banned. You should try to find out why they don't want to just make an update - it would be much better for them

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. yea i'll try to get down the old app from the itunes.

Comment: @user2555373 No problem! If you want to mark this answer as accepted so others can find it easier, you can click the check mark underneath the voting buttons

Answer (score 0):

What many developers do, is add code to an app that checks a specified endpoint for instructions at each launch. The instructions are either, run as usual or, display this message and URL.

Personally, I would do this, and also update the old app as a freebie teaser for the new app. Apple pays less attention to reductions in functionality than they do to "kills".

Run the teaser for a year or so, then kill it.